# Flexbox wrapping in a nested container

Tags: html, flexbox

I've got a full-page flexbox column container which itself contains:

- a "red" column flexbox container with 3 fixed-size boxes
- a "green" row flexbox container with 5 fixed-size boxes

I'd like both of these nested containers to wrap their content when the window size shrinks.

It works well for the green row container when the windows shrinks horizontally, but I fail to get it to work for the red one (when reducing the size vertically).

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ko3yfk2/

HTML:

```
<div style="position:absolute;
            top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px;
            overflow:hidden;

            display:flex;
            justify-content:flex-start;
            align-items:stretch;
            flex-direction:column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;">

<div style='flex:auto;
                background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
                display:flex;
                justify-content:space-between;
                align-items:stretch;
                flex-direction:column;
                flex-wrap: wrap;'>
    <div id='redBox' style="flex:none">Box 1</div>
    <div id='redBox' style="flex:none">Box 2</div>
    <div id='redBox' style="flex:none">Box 3</div>
</div>

<div style='flex:none;
                background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
                display:flex;
                justify-content:space-between;
                align-items:stretch;
                flex-direction:row;
                flex-wrap: wrap;'>
    <div id='greenBox' style="flex:none">Box 5</div>
    <div id='greenBox' style="flex:none">Box 6</div>
    <div id='greenBox' style="flex:none">Box 7</div>
    <div id='greenBox' style="flex:none">Box 8</div>
    <div id='greenBox' style="flex:none">Box 9</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#redBox {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
#greenBox {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky one. Apparently, in order for `flex: auto` to work with `flex-wrap`, you need to have a `height` or a `min-height` on your element.

I don't know if this is according to the spec, but it seems to work this way:

`min-height: 100px` ensures that the red container never gets smaller than the boxes. The `height` and `max-height` on the outer container provide the growth/shrink context for the red container, but are not necessary in this example:

```
<div style="position:absolute;
        top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px;

        display:flex;
        justify-content:flex-start;
        align-items:start;
        flex-direction:column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
                max-height: 100%;
                height: 100%;">

    <div style='flex: 1 1 auto;background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
          display:flex;
          justify-content:space-between;
          align-items:stretch;
          flex-direction:column;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          min-height: 100px;'> <!-- this is the magic -->
        <div id='redBox' style="flex:none">Box 1</div>
        <div id='redBox' style="flex:none">Box 2</div>
        <div id='redBox' style="flex:none">Box 3</div>
    </div>

    <div style='flex:none;background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
          display:flex;
          justify-content:space-between;
          align-items:stretch;
          flex-direction:row;
          flex-wrap: wrap;'>
        <div id='greenBox' style="flex:none">Box 5</div>
        <div id='greenBox' style="flex:none">Box 6</div>
        <div id='greenBox' style="flex:none">Box 7</div>
        <div id='greenBox' style="flex:none">Box 8</div>
        <div id='greenBox' style="flex:none">Box 9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ko3yfk2/1/

Comment: Awesome! That solves my problem indeed. Thanks a lot Nils!